Can an office 365 addin write and execute an office script?
I have an Excel spreadsheet for which I have written an office 365 addin hosted in Microsoft Azure. The addin creates a Taskpane for the user which makes their interactions with the spreadsheet more straightforward.
One of the things that the addin does is similar to an Excel Data Table where it loops through possible values for several variables and records the results of several calculations. I am confident that I could write an office script to perform this task. This would seem like a better solution as the office 365 addin is hosted in Azure and thus costs money to run this loop.
My question is whether I could get the addin to write the office script for Excel, send it to Excel and get Excel to execute the script locally.
I am trying to limit the complexity of distribution of the Excel spreadsheet. Ideally, it would be accessible only through the web based version of Excel. Second, I would like all user interaction with the spreadsheet to be via the taskpane. In theory, I could write the office script, figure out how to distribute it with the spreadsheet, but I would have to add a button to the spreadsheet that executes the script. I would want that button on the taskpane created by the office 365 addin.
So far, I have written the code into the office 365 addin. This works fine but I am concerned that there is a cost to using Azure in this way.

you can make you script in Script Lab Add-in https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380862?tab=Overview

I have written office scripts and executed them via buttons embedded in the spreadsheet. The office 365 addin allows me to create a taskpane where i can place buttons and other functionality. The user interacts with the spreadsheet primarily through the taskpane. The reason I am asking my question, is that it seems like an office script is a reasonable solution for what I want to do, but it makes a mess of my user experience.

host it on Github for free
